# How to make two different header in multi page application using Angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an application having home page which has a header. But on click on a button in home page, i want to navigate to another page having different header and the content inside that page rendered into `ng-view` and on the change of the URL, `ng-view` content will change at the same time the header also needed to change. Please anybody give some idea to do this.

Comment: Can you please add some more code or provide a plunker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use state router for that.

In ng router unfortunately you cannot have multiple views on a pageEg: define routing as:

```
.state('/',{

    header:{
        templateUrl: 'urlpathHeader',
        controller: headerController
    },
    content: {
         templateUrl: 'urlpathContent',
         controller: ContentController
    },


})
.state('other',{

    header:{
        templateUrl: 'otherurlpathHeader',
        controller: OtherheaderController
    },
    content: {
         templateUrl: 'urlpathContent',
         controller: ContentController
    },


})
```

In your view (html)

```
<div ui-view="header">
<div ui-view="content">
```

Find the documentation here for clarity:

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

Comment: Thanks @Rahul this is really helpful and it worked.

Comment: @KISHANPATI: Please accept my answer if it helped you

Answer (score 0):

Moving the header into your ng-view, but I would rather use ngRoute and nested ui-view's https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router